# Implementing Microsoft's Project Oxford - Emotion API and file upload

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, windows, azure-cognitive-services

I'm looking to be able to implement the Emotion API from Project Oxford on my website. I've currently written the below HTML/JavaScript code which checks an image from a URL and displays the result of said image after having run the Emotion API:

```
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize",
      beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
        // Request headers
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "my-key");
      },
      type: "POST",
      // Request body
      data: '{"url": "https://philosophybank.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/happy-people.jpg"}',
    })
    .done(function(data) {
    JSON.stringify(data);
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      //console.log(data);
      //alert(data.scores);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      console.log(error.getAllResponseHeaders());

      alert("fail");
    });
});

</script>
```

This code works fine, however I'm looking to implement this on my website such that people upload images themselves locally from their machine with the use of a browse button as opposed to looking up an image using the link. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I've had a look at the [API documentation][1] and it looks like the Body can be posted as either `application/json` or `application/octet-stream`. If you post the body as octet-stream you'll be able to directly post the binary object (the image) to the api.

If I go to the trouble of mocking this up for you and updating this post, will you mark it as an answer? (providing it works)


  [1]: https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/563b31ea778daf121cc3a5fa

Comment: Hi, sounds like you're right, just had a quick look at this! It would be extremely helpful if you could help me out with this! I'm new to JavaScript and APIs so your help will be very much appreciated. I will indeed mark it as an answer as this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, I'll try to mock something up in the next day or so. You want this as pure Javascript or are you using ASP.Net?

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! JavaScript would be perfect, as then I'll be able to write this in my pre existing HTML website. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mocked this up using `application/octet-stream` as the body type which allows you to post a binary object (i.e. the image itself), rather than a url to an image. The [Emotion API documentation](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/563b31ea778daf121cc3a5fa) details how this is a supported content type.

I've continued with use of JQuery as per your original example.

You should be able to copy and paste this entire example into a HTML file, add your Emotion API key where it says `my-key` and it will work

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="filename">
    <button id="btn">Click here</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btn').click(function () {

            var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

            $.ajax({
                    url: "https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize",
                    beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
                        // Request headers
                        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "my-key");
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    data: file,
                    processData: false
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    JSON.stringify(data);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                })
                .fail(function(error) {
                    alert(error.getAllResponseHeaders());
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice! Anybody got a similar code working with Text to Speech?